# Calling Base Class Functions with Inherited Type

Tags: c++, class, function, inheritance

I can't describe exactly what I want to say but I want to use base class functions with an inherited type. Like I want to declare "Coord3D operator + (Coord3D);" in one class, but if I use it with Vector3D operands, I want it to return Vector3D type instead of Coord3D.

With this line of code below, I add two Vector3D's and get a Coord3D in return, as told to me by the typeid().name() function. How do I reorganize my classes so that I get a Vector3D on return?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
using namespace std;

class Coord3D
{
public:
        float x, y, z;
        Coord3D (float = 0.0f, float = 0.0f, float = 0.0f);
        Coord3D operator + (Coord3D &);
};

Coord3D::Coord3D (float a, float b, float c)
{
        x = a;
        y = b;
        z = c;
}

Coord3D Coord3D::operator+ (Coord3D &param)
{
        Coord3D temp;
        temp.x = x + param.x;
        temp.y = y + param.y;
        temp.z = z + param.z;
        return temp;
}

class Vector3D: public Coord3D
{
public:
        Vector3D (float a = 0.0f, float b = 0.0f, float c = 0.0f)
        : Coord3D (a, b, c) {};
};

int main ()
{
        Vector3D a (3, 4, 5);
        Vector3D b (6, 7, 8);
        cout << typeid(a + b).name();
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: what do you expect to happen here and what do you want to happen

Comment: I want Vector3Ds to be able to add each other by using the functions derived from Coord3D, but when they do add, they turn into a Coord3D instead of a Vector3D.

Comment: You have to define an `operator+` in `Vector3D` that returns a `Vector3D` instead of a `Coord3D`.

Comment: Could you just make a operator+ in Vector3D that calls the base class?

Comment: So I have to create a whole new function instead of base it off of Coord3D's functions? Is there another way, because the first way is really verbose and kinda defeats the purpose of OOP.

Comment: @KeinMitleid I agree that it would be verbose to reiterate all of the arithmetic functions, but I don't think this really falls under OOP concepts; OOP is more focused on a base class interface that child types then reimplement differently.  In this example, Vector3D just subsumes Coord3D.

Answer (score 1):

The functionality you want is in the base class, but it returns a base class (which makes sense since the `Coord3D` has no idea what a `Vector3D` is).  If you are adamant about not rewriting `operator+()` for `Vector3D` (which I think is fair if you plan to have multiplication and such as well), you can instead create a copy constructor in the `Vector3D` class that can construct a `Vector3D` from the `Coord3D` result.

```
class Vector3D: public Coord3D
{
public:
        Vector3D (float a = 0.0f, float b = 0.0f, float c = 0.0f)
        : Coord3D (a, b, c) {};

        Vector3D (const Coord3D& param){ new ((Coord3D*)this) Coord3D(param); }
};

int main ()
{
        Vector3D a (3, 4, 5);
        Vector3D b (6, 7, 8);
        Vector3D c = a + b;
        cout << typeid(c).name();
        Sleep(1000);
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Um, isn't that 'new' going to leak memory like crazy?  Hmm, or is that placement_new and all is well.

Comment: It's not actually allocating any more space; the constructor has already created a nice little slot in memory for the `Vector3D` object that looks like `[Coord3D Vector3D]`.  Basically, the base class is concatenated with the derivative class in memory.  With placement new, we are telling it to put the `Coord3D` that results from the addition into the base class location within the `[Coord3D Vector3D]` slot.

Comment: @Aggieboy Are you sure? There are now three floats on the heap and they will be copied to the stack; so the three floats on the heap are now dangling pointers. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @rwols look at [this reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/new/operator%20new/).  The version that applies here is the **(3) placement** which explicitly says placement new *simply returns ptr (no storage is allocated).*  The pointer returned by the placement new is just `this`.  There is nothing allocated on the heap in my code, and therefore no dangling pointers.